# What is the best Drupal Survey module

Tags: drupal, open-source, content-management-system, module, survey

We're after a replacement for a DotNetNuke installation with a DynamicForms module by DataSprings.

Currently the problems are mainly performance related, but the fact that DynamicForms uses Postbacks on ASP.Net all the time renders it also highly susceptible to slow server response time.

We're after a Drupal module which would allow us to present the CMS user with a control panel where they could:
- create new surveys
- assign a target group for the surveys
- manage the questions:
  - checkbox/radiobutton/combobox/open questions
  - variations of the above - e.g. a combobox with a text field when "other" was chosen
  - the support for data lists, e.g. "what state do you live in" with values stored in the database and managed separately.
  - conditional questions (show/hide) further questions when a certain option is chosen
  - grouping questions (hiding sets of questions at a time)
  - scrapbook function (storing frequent questions and being able to easily copy them into the new poll)
  - exporting the poll data along with selected attributes from the user profile

As you can see the requirements are huge, and we're looking for an Open Source alternative to the current solution, which would allow us to extend the module if necessary.

Drupal would be the platform of choice, but we're flexible in that respect.

I'd appreciate your suggestions of alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

There is a similar discussion going on at [Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/717098). IMHO, Drupal just isn't perfect for complex surveys. [Limesurvey](http://www.limesurvey.org/) is much better when it comes to different types of questions, conditional blocks, reusable question types etc. However in Limesurvey 1, the admin interface is awkward and theming/templating system is not great. [Limesurvey 2](http://docs.limesurvey.org/tiki-index.php?page=LimeSurvey+2.0+Roadmap) looks [very promising](http://devdemo2.limesurvey.org/users/login), but it's in beta.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at the Limesurvey and it looks good, but doesn't readily integrate into any CMS backend, as does the DNN module.

Will keep looking :)

Comment: Since Drupal and Limesurvey are both PHP/MySQL, it should be very doable to write your own module for some basic integration (like sharing users and making survey results available in Drupal's Views module).

Answer (score 3):

Your best choice should be a new drupal module integrating the LimeSurvey software :

http://drupal.org/project/limesurvey_sync

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform)

Comment: I did, but it seems like it's not a survey module, but a generic web form module.

I'm concerned that the UI for the user would be a bit opaque and the functionalities we need (database stored answers and profile links) would have to be manually bolted on.

Also I'm not sure it actually supports field groups and events (on change of this hide that)

Comment: I've used webform to create this survey.
Basically you create a set of question fields (text, textarea, radios, select, radio, check, email or file), you also create groups and one of the settings is to split the groups into separate pages.
Here's an example.
http://www.bankeyfields.co.uk/survey-making-your-community-site-better

The results can then be extracted into csv or excel.

Comment: Results exported by webform are horrible