# Orient the contents with a survey in drupal

Tags: redirect, drupal, survey

I use the Drupal CMS.

I would like to have a survey on the home page, depending on the answers redirects to a list of content.

- Can I use a module for this?
- Do you have any idea how I could proceed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [limesurvey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2287554/3202287)
2. Webform
3. Nothing works out fine then try going the custom way.

Use Rules module to redirection when survey is complete.
surveybuilder, deepsurvey plenty of contrib modules are available checkout.

*
*I haven't tried this just passing the info where you can start*

Answer (score 0):

I'm recommending webform module.

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform

I just don't think that it can redirect to different page depending on answers out of box, but you can always add custom submit handler and do redirection on your own:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5861/how-to-redirect-to-a-page-after-submitting-a-form